# Connecting to USB 3G modem and sending SMS with PHP

Tags: php, sms, modem, 3g

I've read most of the posts regarding this matter but I find nothing that is relevant to my problem.

I don't know how to connect to the modem with php code.
I would greatly appreciate any help or links to where I can find the code.

I have a Sierra Wireless 3G modem. It is connected to Port_#0006.Hub_#0003

I found that the commands sent to the modem should look something like below

```
AT+CMGF=1
OK<br>
AT+CMGS="+31123456789"
> This is the text message.→
+CMGS: 198
OK
```

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about PHP? That's a server-side script language. Are you plugging in your 3G modem to your server machine where you are running your web server?

Comment: Yes the modem is plugged into the server. Its fixed now turns out the ethernet drivers were installed not the serial ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases the Wireless modem will create a virtual serial port

- On Windows look at device manager, `View->Devices by Connection` and
  follow the tree back from the modem to find the `COMn` port (n being
  what you need to identify).
- On linux look for /dev/ttyUSBn (again n being what you need to identify).

You can then `fopen()` the device file (`\\.\comn` on Windows, `/dev/ttyUSBn` on Linux) and `fwrite()` your comands there.

Comment: Yes I am having difficulty locating this virtual port. I tried viewing devices by connection but it still says Port_#0006.Hub_#0003. Do you have any suggestions how to locate this port?

Comment: Port_#0006.Hub_#0003 is the USB device path, I am quite sure, there must be a "normal" COM port name. If you locate your Modem on viewing devices by connection, please post the chain of device names from the modem back to the root of the tree

Comment: Intel(R) 5 series/3400 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 3B3C
->USB Root Hub
-->Generic USB Hub
--->AirLink USB Ethernet/RNDIS #3

Comment: OK, no info there. Which Windows version?

Comment: (Translation might be a bit off, just a german Windows available) Under Control Panel -> Phone and Modem -> Tab "Modems" you see a list, "Modem" and "Connected to", the latter column should be the name of the virtual com port

Comment: It does not pick up my device. I will keep trying tomorrow. Danke shul for your help! If you have any other ideas I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: OK, the problem then is, that you have no drivers installed, so Windows can't create the virtual com port. You need to install the Sierra Wireless 3G drivers for your OS

Comment: Yes thank you! turns out the ethernet drivers were installed not the serial. It works now on COM5!

Answer (score 0):

Your modem driver probably installed a Virtual Serial Port. You need to locate this and then use a library like [php-serial](http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/) to talk to the modem and send the AT commands.

Comment: Yes I am having difficulty locating this virtual port. I tried viewing devices by connection but it still says Port_#0006.Hub_#0003. Do you have any suggestions how to locate this port?